# Error: npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I came across this error while trying to Install Angular CLI using npm.
So the issue is the machine fails to recognize ng as a command and shows the above message when running the angular cli

So.

1. Make sure Node is installed - go to nodejs.org
2. Make sure node -v and npm -v give their respective versions.
3. Make sure typescript is installed, do that using

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Retry

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

If the problem still persists, uninstall nodejs and node js modules completely and reinstall them, make sure paths are set.
Also allow your system to run scripts (eg. ng.js) - to do that - Open windows powershell as an administrator and type the following

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Run the command, it should work now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.